# Blogger post thumbnails are not showing full-sized

Tags: html, css, blogger

## Hi, Blogger post thumbnails are not showing full-sized.  Like this thumbnail it comes cropped automatically.

[see this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCZbi.png)

the CSS of the thumbnail :

```
.entry-thumb, .author-avatar{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .35s ease,filter 0s ease;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="blog-posts hfeed index-post-wrap grid2-items">
<article class="blog-post hentry index-post post-0">
<a class="entry-image-wrap is-image" href="https://www.less1min.com/2022/03/hey.html" title="Hey"><span class="entry-thumb lazy-ify" data-image="https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEgR2UC1vssFRqQfiPv1ooU7Qg76IYEJkq21L81x0Xf9dX5pBcOBn0hZ59eh9soyXAV_w8PoWbZBLhZB440ljEebit-tsH-i6HDrTzCJYAirIrA7pF7SBKVnzyZ305p3PXwqjDvYQyYSTPokBoj7bxvkG5FonnGo9MUg55DszbffAv5PPRPjPFh3TZ9g=w72-h72-p-k-no-nu" style="background-image:url(https://blogger.googleusercontent.com/img/a/AVvXsEgR2UC1vssFRqQfiPv1ooU7Qg76IYEJkq21L81x0Xf9dX5pBcOBn0hZ59eh9soyXAV_w8PoWbZBLhZB440ljEebit-tsH-i6HDrTzCJYAirIrA7pF7SBKVnzyZ305p3PXwqjDvYQyYSTPokBoj7bxvkG5FonnGo9MUg55DszbffAv5PPRPjPFh3TZ9g=w259-h167-p-k-no-nu)"></span>
</a>
<div class="entry-header">
<h2 class="entry-title"><a class="entry-title-link" href="https://www.less1min.com/2022/03/hey.html" rel="bookmark" title="Hey">Hey</a></h2>
<p class="entry-excerpt excerpt">
</p>
<div class="entry-meta">
<span class="entry-time mi"><time class="published" datetime="2022-03-29T14:49:00+03:00">مارس 29, 2022</time></span>
</div>
</div>
</article>
</div>
```

**I want to show the full size of the image in the thumbnail.**

Comment: Can you share also your `html` code? That would ne helpful.

Comment: I have addede it

Comment: What is full sized? page width, element width of the post? Its not defined. Your width, and height are based on it's parent. We dont know it's parent. And in my oppinion, using a span for images, not a good idea, span are inline elements. Better use a div or an image element

Comment: Would you accept the answer if it solved the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Change this `background-size: cover;` to `background-size: fill;`